# Find the general solution of $y''+\alpha^2y=\tan(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I would really appreciate help with the above.

A hint that is given to me is to examine the special cases of $\alpha = 0, 1, -1$

Ok with that

Case 1: $\alpha = 1$ then the DE is $y''+y = \tan(x)$

Characteristic Equation of Homo DE is ($\lambda^2+1=0)$

Case 2: $\alpha = 0$ then the DE is $y'' = \tan(x)$

Characteristic Equation of homo DE is ($\lambda^2=0)$

Case 3: $\alpha = -1$ then the DE is $y'' +y = \tan(x)$

Characteristic Equation of Homo DE is ($\lambda^2 + 1=0)$

Ok, but I don't know where to go from here. I don't even know if this methodology is right. I would appreciate some help here

Any help would be greatly appreciated thank you.

Comment: The general case is almost intractable. The solution is here https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%27+%2B+a%5E2+y+%3D+tan%28x%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second case you should be able to solve the DE:
$$y''=\tan x$$
Integrate twice.
$$y'=c_1-\ln |\cos x|$$
$$y=c_1x+c_2-\int \ln |\cos x|dx  $$

---

You made a mistake maybe you have to consider $\alpha^2 =0,1,-1$. Because $\alpha =-1 \implies \alpha ^2 =1$

---

For the first case:
$$y''+y = \tan(x)$$
What you find is correct:
$$\lambda^2+1=0 \implies \lambda= \pm i$$
The solution to the homogeneous DE is:
$$y(x)=c_1 \sin x +c_2 \cos x$$
For the ingomogeneous DE, you need to apply [the method of variation of parameters.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters)

---

For $\alpha \ne 0,1,-1$ you can rewrite the DE as
$$y''+\alpha^2y=\tan(x)$$
Multiply both side by $\cos (\alpha x)$:
$$(\cos (\alpha x)y')'+\alpha(\sin (\alpha x) y)'=\tan(x) \cos (\alpha x)$$
And integrate. Then the DE becomes a first order.

Comment: Yes the solution is the sum of the particular solution and the general one @BadwaterBarry $y=y_p+y_h$

Comment: Check again because $y_p = -cos(x)sin(x) + cos(x)sin(x) - cos(x)ln|tan(x)+sec(x)| $ is simply $y_p = - cos(x)ln|tan(x)+sec(x)|$ @BadwaterBarry

Comment: Yes you have to use the Wronskian for that method you're right. @BadwaterBarry

Comment: Ok thank you very much!

Comment: You're very welcome @BadwaterBarry

Comment: $\int -\log (\cos (x)) \, dx$ is all but trivial

Comment: I meant that the DE can be integrated twice no need for any special ethod. Now I agree with you some integrals are far from being trivial @Raffaele

Comment: No, really, You didn't try to compute that integral, did you? This is what *Mathematica* gave me:
$$\int \tan (x) \cos (a x) \, dx=\frac{e^{-i a x} \left(a (a+2) e^{2 i x} \, _2F_1\left(1,1-\frac{a}{2};2-\frac{a}{2};-e^{2 i x}\right)-(a-2) \left((a+2) \left(\, _2F_1\left(1,-\frac{a}{2};1-\frac{a}{2};-e^{2 i x}\right)-e^{2 i a x} \, _2F_1\left(1,\frac{a}{2};\frac{a}{2}+1;-e^{2 i x}\right)\right)+a e^{2 i (a+1) x} \, _2F_1\left(1,\frac{a}{2}+1;\frac{a}{2}+2;-e^{2 i x}\right)\right)\right)}{2 a \left(a^2-4\right)}$$

Comment: No I didn't But I know from WA that it"s complicated @Raffaele